# express.js 4: catch bodyParser error in router's errorHandler

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

How can I catch a bodyParser error in a router's errorHandler in express.js 4?

Example code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// use bodyParser.json()
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// setup route /test
var testRouter = express.Router();
testRouter.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('not implemented'));
});
testRouter.use('/', function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.send('testRouter error: ' + err.message);
});
app.use('/test', testRouter);

// default error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.send('default error handler: ' + err.message);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Sending a `POST` request to `/test` with an empty body will return `testRouter error: not implemented`. This message comes from the error handler which is defined in the `testRouter`, and this is what I expect to happen.

Sending a `POST` request to `/test` with a malformed json body, however, will return `default error handler: [bodyParser error]`. This message comes from the default error handler.

I want the error handler in the `testRouter` to handle all bodyParser errors that occur on requests to `/test`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `testRouter` use the body parser middleware:

```
// not this:
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// but this:
testRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Otherwise the default router will handle the error, like you noticed.

If you *also* want to use the body parser middleware for the default router, make sure that you declare it *after* you added `testRouter`:

```
app.use('/test', testRouter);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: But why? I thought all middleware is applied in the order in which it is registered, and the testRouter error handler is registered before the default error handler...

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer because it answers my initial question. However I found a slightly different approach having the error handler outside of the router - see my own answer.

Comment: @x-ray I +1'd your answer, nice solution =D

Answer (score 1):

[robertklep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30874228/846987) is the answer to my question how to catch bodyParser errors in a router's errorHandler. However, I found a slightly different solution *without* catching the error *inside* the router. My basic idea was that I wanted to put everything related to an api exposed under `/api/v1.0` into a router in a javascript module - including an error handler that outputs errors in the format required by the api. Thus I had the following line in `app.js`:

```
app.use('/api/v1.0', require('./routes/api/v1.0/api'));
```

`api.js` exported an `express.Router()`. This router would never handle errors from 'outside' of the router. (See also GitHub issues [catch error of "toplevel" app.use-middlewear in router error handler #2679](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2679) and [Inconsistent behavior with error-handling middleware in routers #2633](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2633)).

To catch all errors with an api specific error handler, api router and api error handler have to be separated. That can be done like this:

`api.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/endpoint', require('./endpoint'));

var errorHandler = function (err, req, res, next) {
  // all errors need to be returned in json
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({ error: err.message });
};

module.exports.router = router;
module.exports.errorHandler = errorHandler;
```

`app.js`:

```
var api = require('./routes/api/v1.0/api');
app.use('/api/v1.0', api.router);
app.use('/api/v1.0', api.errorHandler);
```

This way the api's error handler still only handles requests to `/api/v1.0`, but can catch all errors, including e.g. errors from bodyParser defined as app-level middleware.